# How can I fill out a table column with specific text from adjacent column in Excel?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am using Excel to house a database for qualitative transcripts (copied from Word). Every transcript follows the same outline, having sections for different topics addressed in questions. When I paste the transcripts, I would like to have a column to the left of the text that recognizes the section title and populates the column with that section header until the next section header comes up. Right now, I am manually typing the section title and dragging it until the next section starts.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yava7.png)

Comment: My guess is that you would need to code something in VBA to do this.  Maybe you should add VBA to your tag list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function in column B to get this, as long as every section starts with the word "Section" and everything that isn't a section heading doesn't start with the word "Section".

```
=IF(LEFT(C2,7) = "Section",C2,B1)
```

In your example, if you pasted this function in cell B2 and fill down (to keep relative references), it should do the trick.

Comment: That will be a decent patch for now. Thank you.

Comment: Does this not meet your requirements? If you had a different kind of solution in mind please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing with VBA

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FillDownInfo()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lastRowC As Long, rng As Range

    With ActiveSheet

       lastRowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

       For Each rng In .Range("B2:B" & lastRowC)
           If InStr(1, rng.Offset(, 1).Value, "Section") > 0 Then
               rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
           Else
              rng = rng.Offset(-1, 0)
           End If
       Next rng
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```